# Is ThinkPad X61T SD card slot SDXC compatible?

Tags: windows-xp, thinkpad, sd-card

I have a Thinkpad X61T 7763 tablet and I was planning to buy a 64GB card for the SD card slot. The 64GB card supports the new SDXC standard and I'm not sure if the SD card driver / hardware can handle that. So far, I've successfully used 8GB cards in the slot, but they were SDHC ones. Thinkpad manuals don't give the answer. I wonder if anyone tried this configuration already and what was the outcome.

Answer (score 3):

Lenovo didn't add SDXC support to their laptops until 2010 (after the SDXC standard was announced in 2009). The X61T is from 2007, so no, it won't support SDXC cards.

The largest capacity cards I've seen the X61T reported to support are 16 GB SDHC cards.

Comment: Thanks for the response. From what I've read, adding support for "basic" SDXC cards (version <=3.0, non UHS) is often only a software upgrade. What's interesting is that the SD card reader driver is from Microsoft (not from Lenovo) and the driver date is 2002.

Answer (score 0):

SD card slot obviously will not read sdhc or sdxc cards.

no logo no guaranteed compatibility https://www.sdcard.org/consumers/sdxc_capabilities/using_sdxc/

Comment: *obviously will not read sdhc* ... *So far, I've successfully used 8GB cards in the slot, but they were SDHC ones.*... so, you have any evidence to back up your claim they *will not*? Because the OP has confirmed they *will*.

Comment: As I recall, most cameras and portable devices that supported SDHC simply advertised an "SD" or "microSD" slot. And a lot of devices that didn't support SDHC originally were able to support it after a firmware update. But the differences between SDXC and SDHC are probably greater than that between SDHC and SDSC.

Comment: "IT DEPENDS"

3.3V 4GB and 8GB cards are not popular but worked fine in 3.3V-only SD adapters (where "also standard" 1.8V-only cards of same capacity did not)
Same may or may not apply to cards a small bit into SDXC world.